# Linking in llvm

Tags: gcc, llvm, clang, llvm-gcc

I am profiling a few files in Spec2K6 benchmark with a profiler written in LLVM, and cannot understand what is the correct way to link multiple .bc files.

For example, the benchmark has concat.c, which uses the xmalloc method defined in xmalloc.c, which uses xexit method from xexit.c

I am using the following commands to link multiple .bc files before I profile them -

```
CFLAGS='-D_GNU_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -c -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -g -O0 -    I/net/x/silkyar/llvm/include -I/net/403.gcc/src'
clang $CFLAGS -emit-llvm -c 403.gcc/src/concat.c -o concat.bc
clang $CFLAGS -emit-llvm -c 403.gcc/src/xexit.c -o xexit.bc
clang $CFLAGS -emit-llvm -c 403.gcc/src/xmalloc.c -o xmalloc.bc 
llvm-link concat.bc xexit.bc xmalloc.bc -o a.bc
llc a.bc -o a.s
g++ -o final a.s
./final
```

but this fails with,
llvm-link: link error in 'xexit.bc': Linking globals named 'xexit': symbol multiply defined!
/tmp/ccUldT0Y.o:(.debug_info+0x1e): undefined reference to `.Lline_table_start0'
/tmp/ccUldT0Y.o:(.debug_info+0x42f): undefined reference to`.Lline_table_start1'
/tmp/ccUldT0Y.o:(.debug_info+0x4a0): undefined reference to `.Lline_table_start2'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Could anyone please guide me on how llvm-link works.

Thanks.

Comment: In the older LLVM versions you could find a very useful tool `llvm-ld`, which mimicked the GNU ld behaviour. Someone removed it later for no reason, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, `llvm-link` works fine. Here's a simple demonstration (with LLVM built from trunk a few days ago):

```
$ cat lib.c 
int libfoo(int x) {
    return x * 2;
}

$ cat user.c
int libfoo(int);


int bar(int a, int b) {
    return a + libfoo(b);
}
$ clang -emit-llvm -c user.c -o user.bc
$ clang -emit-llvm -c lib.c -o lib.bc
$ llvm-link lib.bc user.bc -o linked.bc
$ llvm-dis linked.bc
$ cat linked.ll
; ModuleID = 'linked.bc'
target datalayout = "e-p:64:64:64-i1:8:8-i8:8:8-i16:16:16-i32:32:32-i64:64:64-f32:32:32-f64:64:64-v64:64:64-v128:128:128-a0:0:64-s0:64:64-f80:128:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"

define i32 @libfoo(i32 %x) nounwind uwtable {
entry:
  %x.addr = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %x, i32* %x.addr, align 4
  %0 = load i32* %x.addr, align 4
  %mul = mul nsw i32 %0, 2
  ret i32 %mul
}

define i32 @bar(i32 %a, i32 %b) nounwind uwtable {
entry:
  %a.addr = alloca i32, align 4
  %b.addr = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %a, i32* %a.addr, align 4
  store i32 %b, i32* %b.addr, align 4
  %0 = load i32* %a.addr, align 4
  %1 = load i32* %b.addr, align 4
  %call = call i32 @libfoo(i32 %1)
  %add = add nsw i32 %0, %call
  ret i32 %add
}
```

So you have to carefully examine your specific code for symbol duplication, missing, etc.

Comment: Hi Eli,
So, it turned out that xexit was included multiple times in -I of CFLAGS, and llvm-link worked after removing CFLAGS from the command. 
Thanks for your help.